# Combining lenses from two telescopes to build a more powerful one?

Tags: telescope, telescope-lens, diy

I have two Galileo 700mm x 60mm Astro/Terrestrial Refractor Telescopes. Can I take the lenses out and make one powerful telescope, something like an [optical series circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Series_circuits)?

Comment: No-- the lenses in a telescope have a specific role that can't be performed by a combination of lenses.  You can rig them as giant binoculars though, which some have found worthwhile.

Comment: I suggested an edit to clarify what you are probably after, feel free to roll-back in case my edit does not reflect what you mean.